# Changing Direct Speech to Indirect Speech

Tags: reported-speech

The bus conductor explained,"This seat is set aside for monks".
If I change it into Indirect Speech,will I need to change the demonstrative adjective "this" to "the"? For example:"The bus conductor explained that the seat was set aside for monks." Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The bus conductor explained, "This seat is set aside for monks".

In indirect speech, this will be changed to that.

The bus conductor explained (that) that seat was set aside for monks.